# Single Element Using Lookup operator

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am stuck in an issue with MongoDB. I am using C# driver for MongoDB.

So basically I am trying to join Categories document with Users document. Each category document has one property:

```
public Guid UserId { get; set; }
```

This property is an ObjectId behind the scenes. I have another property:

```
public UserDoc User { get; set; }
```

Now I am trying to fill this User property with all the user details based on the UserId property. This is the code I am trying to achieve this:

```
categoriesCollection.Aggregate()
                .Lookup<CategoryDoc, UserDoc, CategoryDoc>(
                    usersCollection,
                    x => x.UserId,
                    x => x.Id,
                    x => x.User)
```

As expected, 'Lookup' is expecting an array of User documents but I have a property referencing a single user object and thus, it throws an error:

`An error occurred while deserializing the User property of class TatSat.API.Documents.CategoryDoc: Expected a nested document representing the serialized form of a TatSat.API.Documents.UserDoc value, but found a value of type Array instead.`

Can someone help me with this? I am new to Mongo so this is a bit of a pain for me. Kindly note that I am looking for a strongly typed solution and don't want to mess with BsonDocuments if that can be avoided.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a build or runtime error? Can you add the error information?

Comment: @vernou Just edited the original question with the error details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally figured out in some ways. Basically I decided to have another class:

```
public class CategoryDocWithTemporaryData : CategoryDoc
{
   public UserDoc[] Users { get; set; }
   
   public static Expression<Func<CategoryDocWithTemporaryData, CategoryDoc>> ToCategoryDoc => c =>
      new CategoryDoc
      {
         Id = c.Id,
         //other properties
         User = c.Users.First()
      };
    }
```

Then I use the lookup as:

```
categoriesCollection.Aggregate()
   .Lookup<CategoryDoc, UserDoc, CategoryDocWithTemporaryData>(
      usersCollection,
      c => c.UserId,
      c => c.Id,
      c => c.Users)
   .Project(CategoryDocWithTemporaryData.ToCategoryDoc)
```

This, however needs me to use additional projection where I have to manually select all properties which is something I wanted to avoid. But I think I can live with it until I come across a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

`Lookup` will always return an array, even if it only has 1 element.  If you need just the first (or only) document in that array, use a project/set/addFields stage with arrayElemAt.

Comment: Can you share an example on how to do that, using strong-typed fluent API in C#?